# Can I make similar animation only with CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a website and now I have to make an Intro animation exactly like this http://www.elitemodel.fr/

On this website when I load the page, the logo and backgroung is sliding to the left.
My client wants this effect on his website.

For now, I create a page intro.php with this html code:

```
<div class="intro">
    <div class="logo-intro"></div><!-- /.logo logo-intro -->
</div><!-- /.intro -->
<div class="black_overlay"></div><!-- /.logo logo-intro -->
```

I'm trying to make this with css3 and little javascript.

After the html, this is my CSS code for the animation:

```
.intro,
.intro .logo-intro {
    overflow: hidden;
   -moz-animation: slide 2s ease 1.5s forwards;
   -webkit-animation: slide 2s ease 1.5s forwards;
   -o-animation: slide 2s ease 1.5s forwards;
   -ms-animation: slide 2s ease 1.5s forwards;
    animation: slide 2s ease 1.5s forwards;
}

@-moz-keyframes slide /* Firefox */
    {
        from {width: 100%; }
        to {width: 0;}
    }

@-webkit-keyframes slide /* Safari and Chrome */
    {
        from {width: 100%;}
        to {width: 0;}
    }

@-o-keyframes slide /* Opera */
    {
        from {background: white;}
        to {background: black;}
    }

@-ms-keyframes slide /* IE10 */
    {
        from {width: 100%;}
        to {width: 0;}
    }

@keyframes slide
    {
        from {width: 100%;}
        to {width: 0;}
    }

}

.logo-intro  {
    -webkit-animation: logo 1s;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: logo 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 2;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes logo {
    from {top: 50%;}
    to {left: -99999px;}
}

@keyframes logo {
    from {top: 50%;}
    to {left: -99999px;}
}
```

After the animation is over I redirecting intro.php to the home page with javascript

```
// Your application has indicated there's an error
window.setTimeout(function(){
// Move to a new location or you can do something else
var url = "http://www.gaelscalpaesthetics.com/accueil";    
$(location).attr('href',url);
}, 4000);
```

This is working but how can I made this animation without redirecting?

Regards,

Comment: In the javascript you can clearly see that after 4 seconds (4000) the user will be redirected to the given 'url'. If you don't want that just remove of comment (//)  the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/389/)**

```css
body, html {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.logo,
.black-bg {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.logo {
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  animation: animateLogo 2s ease-in-out 1.3s forwards;
}

.black-bg {
  background: black;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateX(100vw);
  animation: animateBlackBg 1.5s ease-in-out 1.5s forwards;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.content img {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}

@keyframes animateLogo {
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    opacity: 1; 
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    opacity: 0; 
  }
}

@keyframes animateBlackBg {
  40% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  80% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="logo">LOGO</div>
<div class="black-bg"></div>

<div class="content">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x900">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x900">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The code is working great. This was my first solution. 
I placed the intro div as a overlay to the home page like your solution, but every time when I go to the home page the animation is loading.

The animation must load only one time on the home page.

Comment: Glad i could help, i suggest you ask another question for that specific problem. Also if this answer or any other one solved your issue, mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can put your code in the homepage and run it when the page loads, after the animation ends, show your content.